# no handler for type [icu_collation_keyword] declared on field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create index with the mapping.

Using URL : localhost:9200/test3?pretty Method : PUT
and with body

```
{  
"mappings": {
"properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      },
      "sort_da": {
        "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
        "index": false,
        "language": "da",
        "country": "DK",
        "variant": "@collation=phonebook"
      },
      "sort_de": {
        "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
        "index": false,
        "language": "de",
        "country": "DE",
        "variant": "@collation=phonebook"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

I'm getting following exception

```
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "no handler for type [icu_collation_keyword] declared on field [sort_de]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to install the ICU Plugin first.

> This plugin can be installed using the plugin manager:
>
> `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu`
>
> The plugin must be installed on every node in the cluster, and each node must be restarted after installation.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu.html